# laravel redirection to route doesn't always work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am writing a logout function and simply after deleting all necessary information from database, I clear session and logout with a redirect. I would like to redirect the user to the home page (landing page) and this did work in another function which is the login (upon successful login, I would redirect to home. Here is how it is done in my code:

```
public function logout()
    {
        $userModel = new User;
        $userToken = Session::get('userToken');
        $isCleared = $userModel->clearSessionForUser($userToken);
        if($isCleared == true)
        {
            Session::forget('userToken');
            Session::flush();
            return Redirect::route('/');        
        }else{
            $errorArray = array('errorMsg'=>'logout operation didn't succeed  ');
            return View::make('errors.error', $errorArray);
        }
    }
```

the routes.php has the following route:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
```

and I've done this before as I said with login and it worked but here it is saying:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [/] not defined.
```

Here is how the login part containing the redirect looks like:

```
$userModel = new User;
        $isUser = $userModel->validateDetails($email, $password);
        if($isUser==true)
        {
            return Redirect::route('/');
        }else{
            $errorArray = array('errorMsg'=>'The credentials doesn\'t match any user records or the account has not been activated ');
            return View::make('errors.error', $errorArray);
        }
```

Please support and let me know why it works once and not again although both are methods in the same class and targeting the same route.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter in Redirect::route should be the route name. So, if you modified your routes file as such:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MainController@index'));
```

Then you can utilize that route name in Redirect::route:

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

Alternatively, you can simply use Redirect::to, to redirect to a URL:

```
return Redirect::to('/'); // This is the URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is related - but you have a syntax error:

```
$errorArray = array('errorMsg'=>'logout operation didn't succeed  ');
```

should be

```
$errorArray = array('errorMsg'=>"logout operation didn't succeed  ");
```

or

```
$errorArray = array('errorMsg'=>'logout operation didn\'t succeed  ');
```

Comment: Actually that bit (the message for logout error) was modified for the sake of this post. It was in Arabic and made it english just to clarify my intention. The same line used here was used across different other areas of the application and it works. Appreciate the attempt though